# How to print a for loop within a for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, random, formatting

Beginner in Java. Have history in C and Python though.

I'm trying to take this code:

```
package javaman;
import java.util.Random;
public class JavaMan{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomInteger = 0;
        float average = 0;
        System.out.println("The 3 Numbers are:");
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            randomInteger = random.nextInt(51);
            System.out.println(randomInteger);
            average = average + randomInteger;
        }
        average = average/3;
        System.out.println("The average of the three random numbers (between 0-50) is: " + average);
    }
}
```

And make it so that it prints out the following:

```
The 3 Numbers are: 
Number 1 is: 32
Number 2 is: 16
Number 3 is: 0
The average of the three random numbers (between 0-50) is: 16.0
```

However, I have programmed it such that whenever I use randomInteger, it just runs through the whole for loop when I want the for loop to have its own for loop (the whole "Number x is:" is absent...it just prints the 3 numbers and spits out the average): in the sense that **I would be like the following...**

```
("Number", i, "is:", randomInteger) this would look like "Number 1 is: 16"
("Number", i, "is:", randomInteger) this would look like "Number 2 is: 15"
("Number", i, "is:", randomInteger) etc.
```

How do I make that in Java?

Comment: `System.out.println("Number " + i + " is: " + randomInteger);`, if that's too hard, you could also use `System.out.printf` which works the same way that `printf` does in C

Comment: bingo! my gosh. you know, i could swear on my life i tried that exact thing, but it didn't work. i think i used "i++" inside println and it wasn't biting. thank you so much. Would you happen to know how to get it to start from 1? I think i+1 isn't working...Nevermind...I got it! I needed to put in paranthesis....sheesh! The formatting here is something else. Thanks Mad Man.

Comment: `System.out.printf("Number %d is: %d%n", i + 1, randomInteger);`

Comment: `+ (i + 1) + `, this way it can resolve the additional before trying to convert it to a `String` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `System.out.println ("Number "+i+" is:"+randomInteger);`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomInteger = 0;
    float average = 0;
    System.out.println("The 3 Numbers are:");
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        randomInteger = random.nextInt(51);
        //  System.out.println(randomInteger);
        System.out.println ("Number "+i+" is:"+randomInteger);
        average = average + randomInteger;
    }
    average = average/3;
    System.out.println("The average of the three random numbers (between 0-50) is: " + average);
}
```

Comment: to start from 1     for (int i=1; i<3; i++)